# How do I ascertain the CONTACT linked to an S_EVT_ACT record?

Tags: siebel

Apologies if this is very basic but I'm fairly new to Siebel.

I have four activity record IDs and I need to find out to which contact they are attached in the database.

I'm assuming a join somewhere, but I don't know the Schema well enough and I can't see an obvious contact ID in the S_EVT_ACT table.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The S_CONTACT row_id exists in the TARGET_PER_ID column of the S_EVT_ACT table.

If you can't get it from that you can use the S_ACT_CONTACT intersection table.